# how do i split an integer N into two non-empty parts by cutting it between any pair of consecutive digits. such that pair of integers A, B is created

Tags: python

Expected input:

```
n = 1234
```

Expected output:

```
A = 1
B = 234

or

A = 12
B = 34

or
A = 123
B = 4
```

I am trying to find the minimum absolute difference between these pairs.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In general the arithmetic way of cutting an integer is with integer division and modulo arithmetic:

```
def cut(n: int, places: int):
    d = 10 ** places
    return divmod(n, d)  # equivalent to (n // d, n % d)

A, B = cut(1234, 1)
```

Comment: Can also be `return divmod(n, d)`!